# To find the dimension of the intersection of $N(A)$ and $R(B)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A=$

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 0 \\\ -1 & 5 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$, $B=$

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \\\ -1 & 0 \\\ 3 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

$N(A)$ the null space of $A$ and $R(B)$ the range space of $B$. Then find the dimension of the intersection of $N(A)$ and $R(B)$.

dim$N(A) = 1, $ dim$R(B) = 2$

Now I want use the formula

Dimension of intersection $=$ dimension of $N(A) +$ dimension of $R(B)$ -  dimension of $(N(A) + R(B))$.

But I'm stuck, as I don't know how to find dimension of $(N(A) + R(B))$.

Answer (score 2):

$N(A)=span\{(4,-2,7)\}$

$R(B)=span\{(1,-1,3), (2,0,1)\}$

$(4,-2,7)=2(1,-1,3)+(2,0,1)$

So, $N(A)\cap R(B) = N(A)$

Comment: Can't we take rows of$B$ as span of $B$? 
 i.e.$R(B) = span {(1,2), (-1,0)}$? Since both are linearly independent.

Comment: Rows are not members of $\mathbb{R}^3$. So we can't.